# PowerShell split string loop with switch statement, based on substring, token value

Tags: powershell, switch-statement, substring

Could someone please explain to me why the token value in the following PowerShell code is truncated to the substring value within the switch statement.

Please note the code is for demonstration purposes only so I have kept it as basic as possible. Other switch values would do the same.

Using PowerShell version: 7.3.5

```
$a = 'abc,defg';

$a.Split(",") | `
  ForEach `
  {
    $s = $_;
    write-host "Before" $_;
    Switch ($_.substring(0,1))
    {
      default
        {
          write-host "During" $_;
          write-host "Actual" $s;
        }
    }
    write-host "After" $_;
    write-host "===";
}
```

The output is:

```
Before abc
During a
Actual abc
After abc
===
Before defg
During d
Actual defg
After defg
===
```

Comment: The `$_` in the context of your switch is not the same `$_` in the context of your `ForEach-Object`, I think that's what your question is about?

Comment: `$_` represents the value of the expression passed as argument to the `switch` and can be used in the action block as well as in condition blocks. see the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_psitem?view=powershell-7.2#switch-statement-scriptblocks. The value of `$_` in your `default` block is the result of the `Substring` expression, it is not the result of the first `Split`

Comment: Thank you Santiago. That would explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [automatic variable `$_` (`$PSItem`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#_) has a special meaning not only in the context of `ForEach-Object` but also in the context of a `switch` statement, the value of `$_` in your `default` block represents **the result of the `$_.substring(0, 1)` expression** in your example whereas the `$_` in your `ForEach-Object` statement represents the enumerated values of your `$a.Split(",")` expression.

It's also worth noting that the `switch` statement by itself can enumerate, using the example you have in your questions as an example:

```
switch ('abc,defg'.Split(',')) {
    default {
        'Token: {0}' -f $_
        'Substring: {0}' -f $_.Substring(0, 1)
    }
}
```

The [**about_PSItem** documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_psitem?view=powershell-7.2) presents all contexts where `$_` has a special meaning in PowerShell.

See also [**about_Switch**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2) for details of the `switch` statement.